# Delete a row if a string is found

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a piece of code and I want to delete excess empty rows, by the following criteria

- The row is actually empty
- It is not a Total Row

I am doing this by the below code, which searches for a value of 0 in a certain cell, and then I want it to look for the word Total in a string and not activate the if statement if both of those conditions are not met

Currently my Instr function is not working so I need to change that somehow.

```
Sub Clean_HB()

Dim CLEANHBWS As Worksheet
Set CLEANHBWS = Sheets("Hedgebook")
Dim CLEANFormulaWS As Worksheet
Set CLEANFormulaWS = Sheets("Formula_Template")
Dim Cleanrange As Range

CLEANLastHBR = CLEANHBWS.Cells(CLEANHBWS.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
CLEANClastHBC = CLEANHBWS.Cells(3, CLEANHBWS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
CLEANLastFWSR = CLEANFormulaWS.Cells(CLEANFormulaWS.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
CLEANCLASTFWSC = CLEANFormulaWS.Cells(3, CLEANFormulaWS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

CLEANTickercolumn = CLEANHBWS.Cells.Find(What:="Ticker").Column
CLEANDatecolumn = CLEANHBWS.Cells.Find(What:="Date&Time Booked").Column
CLEANLScolumn = CLEANHBWS.Cells.Find(What:="L/S").Column
CLEANLotscolumn = CLEANHBWS.Cells.Find(What:="Lots").Column
CLEANConversioncolumn = CLEANHBWS.Cells.Find(What:="Conversion Cents").Column
CLEANBorrowcolumn = CLEANHBWS.Cells.Find(What:="Borrow (bps)").Column

For Each Cleanrange In CLEANHBWS.Range(Cells(3, CLEANLotscolumn), Cells(CLEANLastHBR, CLEANLotscolumn))
    If Cleanrange.Value = 0 And Cleanrange.Offset(0, -4).Value <> InStr(1, "total") Then
    Cleanrange.Rows.Select
    Cleanrange.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

EDIT: Picture of workbook, where the Lots column is the column where I want it to check for zero or blanks, and the Date/Time column which also functions as the Total header column

[image]

Appreciate any suggestions

Comment: 0 isn't empty. #Pedant

Comment: `instr(start,string,substring)` yet you've only provided two arguments.

Comment: You always delete rows backwards and more efficient to Union the rows and delete in one go.

Comment: @QHarr not quite sure how to isolate the rows I want and do that, but imagine that yes that is easier.

Comment: Do you wish to delete where 0 or where empty? Remembering the total bit of course. Also, you should fully qualify which sheet you are working with as I can see implicit ActiveSheet references.

Comment: @QHarr Both, this is a cleanup module in my macro that is basically a ledger of positions. So some would have been zeroed out and some would be blank.

Comment: So if there is a single zero or blank in a row (even if other cells are populated) you want to delete? If not total.

Comment: @Qharr I want it to look in a particular cell which represents the total amount of shares for a particular line item(row). If that is zero or blank, and is not a total row, then I want it gone.

Comment: Edited my post with my full code for clarity

Comment: You use variables but then have this line Cleanrange.Offset(0, -4)  which implies a certain position or at least fixed number of columns in order for your instr to work. Is that the case?

Comment: technically the offset refers the same column as CLEANDatecolumn. This is the first column in the workbook and where it would normally represent the date and time for individual lots. It also represents the total row. 

I'll add a screenshot which should make it easier to visualize.

Comment: I'm liking the filter idea in this case.

Comment: You realise that For Each Cleanrange In CLEANHBWS.Range(Cells(3, CLEANLotscolumn) uses an implicit activesheet to determine CleanRange ?

Comment: @Qharr CLeanHBWS should be the Sheet identifier in this case.

Comment: Yes. Mr Rado, unsurprisingly, sorted it :-)

Comment: Glad for the help, the sorting aspect is still a bit out of my league, I'll try to take a page from that book from here on out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for something like the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Dim DelRng As Range ' define a range that will store all rows that needs to be deleted 

' need to add CLEANHBWS also before Cells, to qualify with the sheet you want, and not ActiveSheet 
For Each Cleanrange In CLEANHBWS.Range(CLEANHBWS.Cells(3, CLEANLotscolumn), CLEANHBWS.Cells(CLEANLastHBR, CLEANLotscolumn))
    ' check if cell is empty or equals 0 and not "total" row
    If (Cleanrange.Value = 0 Or Trim(Cleanrange.Value) = "") And InStr(Cleanrange.Offset(0, -4).Value, "total") = 0 Then
        If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then
            Set DelRng = Application.Union(DelRng, Cleanrange)
        Else
            Set DelRng = Cleanrange
        End If
    End If
Next
' make sure there is at least 1 cell inside the range >> delete entire range at 1 line
If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Literally was able to copy and paste it in and it worked perfectly.

Thanks, appreciate the help.